Untranslated date tokens
I'm using Automatic Label and Pathauto to generate patterns for my content from a date field. The problem is that it always ends up being in English, while my site is Dutch only.
The following token shows the month of my field in English, but it should be in Dutch, as I use the same token in other parts of my site, where it is correctly translated.
[node:field_maand:date:custom:F]

I noticed that smart date range fields don't suffer from this issue. The following token renders the pattern in Dutch, just like I would expect it to.
[node:field_datum:value-format:month_and_day]

I don't need a range for all my date fields, so I can't use this as a solution, but it indicates that it's a problem in core I guess?
Anyone who has stumbled on this problem of untranslated date tokens before?

I believe that when you use a default date format like F, it picks up the server language. I believe you will need to set your server locale for it to pick up the date in Dutch. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13848914/1032253

I've added (setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); to my settings.php like you suggested, but it didn't change anything sadly.

What is your browser language? Is it English? I wonder if it may be picking up browser settings.

Also Dutch, as well as the standard language of drupal (and the admin pages).
